# Connecting a corporate device to xCode organizer

Tags: ios, xcode-organizer

I am trying to test my app on as many devices possible.
My girlfriend has her corporate iPhone and I would like very much to try it out.

Are there any repercussions for adding the device to organizer and pairing it with my Mac?
Will my source code or anything else be exposed to their admin?

The company in question hasn't outright banned it but they have pointed out it's not her phone.

Comment: If the admin of the company is smart enough, it just won't work. You should consider to use a service like Hockey. The code will not be visible by the admin but in principle one can get information about the App via decompilation.

Comment: If I remove everything from the device afterwards?